# coerce a multiple output in a new dataframe using ddply

Tags: r, plyr

I have this function:

```
> λ.est <- function(x){
            mle.optim <- mle2(paretoNLL,start=list(λ=-0.7),data=list(x=x),trace=TRUE)
            return(summary(mle.optim)@coef[1,1:4])
            }
```

that fit a distribution and retuns the parameter estimate, std. error, z value and p for my model.
I have to apply this function to different subsets of my original data frame `size` defined by a combination of factor `pond,habitat,treatment,date` , and to do this I'm using the ddply function:

```
> mle.λ <- ddply(size, .(pond,habitat,treatment,date), 
     summarise, λ=λ.est(x=mass.wei))
```

the problem is that, by doing this, I can only add one column a time to the new data frame `mle.λ` , wereas I need to add to  `mle.λ` four new columns, one for each of the outputs of `λ.est` 
basically something that look like this:

```
>  mle.λ
      pond habitat treatment date estimate std. error z value Pr(z)
       -    -        -       -      -        -         -      - 
       -    -        -       -      -        -         -      - 
       -    -        -       -      -        -         -      - 
       -    -        -       -      -        -         -      - 
       -    -        -       -      -        -         -      - 
      ...
```

So far I've been writing a different function for each output needed, but I'd like to do some code economy...is there any way to do it all in one go?

thanks
matteo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you already have a summary function, you don't need to additionally use the `summarise` function. Further, it *is* possible to return more than one output at once. Since there is no example data, here is one that should demonstrate clearly how to do this:

```
n = 20
set.seed(12345)
data = data.frame(cbind(pond=1:2, habitat=1:3, value = rnorm(n)))
```

```
> ddply(data, .(habitat, pond), function(x) summary(x$value))
  habitat pond    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.
1       1    1  0.3706  0.5318  0.6078  0.6767  0.7528  1.1210
2       1    2 -0.9193 -0.6864 -0.4535 -0.1853  0.1817  0.8169
3       2    1 -0.8864 -0.5013 -0.1162 -0.1322  0.2448  0.6059
4       2    2 -0.2762  0.1550  0.4095  0.3131  0.5675  0.7095
5       3    1 -0.7505 -0.5173 -0.2842 -0.3813 -0.1967 -0.1093
6       3    2 -1.8180 -1.0750 -0.3316 -0.1107  0.7429  1.8170
```

Comment: really appriciated John, as always much straightforward than i though...still have to march a lot on the R route..